# Using setAttributeNS in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I need to change the url on all svg's on my page. I have the following code, but get a error when i try to use setAttributeNS.

```
jQuery("[*|href*='icons.svg']:not([href])").each(function () {

  hashedIconUrl = jQuery(this).attr('xlink:href').replace('icons.svg', hashedIcon);
  console.log(hashedIconUrl);

  jQuery(this).setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', hashedIconUrl);
});
```

Comment: `but get an error when I try to use setAttributeNS` what error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: n(...).setAttributeNS is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from the jQuery object to the native DOM object to call setAttributeNS. The usual way to do this is via [0]

```
jQuery("[*|href*='icons.svg']:not([href])").each(function () {

  hashedIconUrl = jQuery(this).attr('xlink:href').replace('icons.svg', hashedIcon);
  console.log(hashedIconUrl);

  jQuery(this)[0].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', hashedIconUrl);
});
```